# Python inheriting at initalization

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization, g-code

Im trying to inherit routines from different classes at initialization based on what a user requests at creation.  My example is a CNCFile class for reading/manipulating/saving a g-code text file.  When its created, a user inputs the type of machine targeted(Fanuc, Okuma, Mitsubishi, etc).  Since all these machines have different ways of handling sub program names and sub calls within a file, I need to write separate classes/functions for each machine.

Here is example of code that does what I want.  It just looks messy.

```
class FanucFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Fanuc file type')

    def subnames(self):
        alist = ['0001', '0002', '0003']
        return alist

    def subcalls(self):
        alist = ['M98 P0002', 'M98 P0003']
        return alist

class OkumaFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Okuma file type')

    def subnames(self):
        alist = ['MAIN', 'SUB1', 'SUB2']
        return alist

    def subcalls(self):
        alist = ['CALL SUB1', 'CALL SUB2']
        return alist

class CNCFile(object):
    def __init__(self, target_machine = 'Fanuc', file_name=None):

        if target_machine == 'Fanuc':
            self.file = FanucFile()

        elif target_machine == 'Okuma':
            self.file = OkumaFile()

        if file_name <> None:
            self.getfile(file_name)
            self.filename = file_name

    def getfile(self, name):
        '''Reads file into list'''
        self.filecont = ['%(Test.cnc)', \
                         'O0001(PART MAIN)', \
                         'N1', \
                         'G00 G17 G20 G40', \
                         'M98 P0002', \
                         'M30', \
                         ' ', \
                         'O0002(SUB 2)', \
                         'M98 P0003', \
                         'M99', \
                         ' ', \
                         'O0003(SUB 2)', \
                         'G91 G28 Z0.', \
                         'M99', \
                         '%']

    def subnames(self): # wrapper around .file.subnames() - seems dumb
        return self.file.subnames()

    def subcalls(self): # wrapper around .file.subcalls() - seems dumb
        return self.file.subcalls()

    def savefile(self):
        for aline in self.filecont:
            print(aline)


if __name__=='__main__':
    #just for testing

    a = CNCFile(target_machine = 'Fanuc', file_name = 'Test.cnc')
    print('File Name : ' + a.filename)
    print('Subs found: ' + str(a.subnames()))
    print('Sub calls : ' + str(a.subcalls()))
    print('Save File :')
    a.savefile()
    print(' ')
```

I end up having to write a wrapper function around the target machine's routines, which seems awkward.

I also see the FanucFile/OkumaFile within the CNCFile later and I'm not sure that's what I want.

```
a = CNCFile(target_machine = 'Fanuc', file_name = 'Test.cnc')
a.subnames()
a.file.subnames()   # redundant
```

I tried inheriting the CNCFile call into the FanucFile or OkumaFile classes, but it got messy when writing the savefile routine in CNCFile when a lot of data was being held by the FanucFile or OkumaFile classes.

Should I be looking at super(), meta classes ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What you've already got (composition-based) is the correct way to go. You can't reasonably use inheritance here.

Comment: Thanks  @ShadowRanger, "composition-based" sheds a lot of light on this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any inheritance in your example.  Typically this would be accomplished with an abstract base class or an "interface" (ie. like Java).  You can use the Abstract Base Class module in Python to accomplish this.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

You can leave a common method name for loading the file and then normalize the output of the files to the greatest degree possible (ie. a common data structure to represent the similar data).